# Apache2.4 & Laravel 5.4 with alias in a subfolder doesn't work without /index.php

Tags: php, laravel, apache, alias

I've created an alias on apache server conf file (/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf) to target the public folder.

```
    Alias /laravel/ "/home/user/dev/web/laravel/public/"

    <Directory "/home/user/dev/web/laravel/public/">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Also, I wrote the following .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/laravel/(.*) /laravel/index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Now, when I'm visitng the `http://IP/laravel` the index.php is loaded as expected. But if I'm gonna make a call to a GET Route like `http://IP/laravel/load_examples` I'm getting back a `NOT FOUND` error.

Instead, if I visit the `http://IP/laravel/index.php/load_examples`, route loaded as expected.

It seems to me that something's going wrong with the .htaccess and rewrite rules.

I tried everything I found on the SO and other places but couldn't find any solution so far.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In the alias before the the code block shown try adding:

`DocumentRoot /home/user/dev/web/laravel/public/`

And then try this for your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Now neither the `/index.php` is loaded when I'm visiting `http://IP/laravel` nor the other routes.

Comment: It sends me to Apache's default index.html